# Flutter showBottomModalPopup height is not extending more than 50% of the screen size

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am trying to use the showBottomModalPopup but I can't seem to get it extended more than  50 % of the screen even tho I am using the the context of the screen to set the height.

Can anyone please spot what I am doing wrong
I am trying to set it to 80%

This the showBottomModal function

```
void _tripShowModalBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .80,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text('this is your first showBottomModal')
      );
    });
  }
```

I am calling it from here

```
onLongPress: () => {
        _tripShowModalBottomSheet(context)
     },
```

full code if needed

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TransportMenuBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const TransportMenuBody({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  void _tripShowModalBottomSheet(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext bc) {
      return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 30,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Text('this is your first showBottomModal')
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  
          ListView(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 10.0),
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                    child: Text('Kigali', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, color: Colors.black),),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onLongPress: () => {
                      _tripShowModalBottomSheet(context)       // calling the function from here
                    },
                    onTap: () => {},
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(child: Text('201', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text('20 active buses', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFd9d9d9)),),),
                              ],),
                              Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text('Kicukiro(saint-joseph) - Down town'),),

                              ],),
                              const Divider(
                                color: Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                                thickness: .5,
                              ),
                              Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(child: Text('201', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600))),
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text('20 active buses', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFd9d9d9)),),),
                              ],),
                              Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text('Kicukiro(saint-joseph) - Down town'),),

                              ],),
                              const Divider(
                                color: Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                                thickness: .5,
                              ),
                            ],)
                        )
                      )
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
                )
            ),
            Text('data'),
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not sure if bottomSheetModal can gain height but if you want a bottom sheet with rich customization you can also use DraggableScrollableSheet which is scrollable by default with nice animation DraggableScrollableSheet you can check this here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html

Comment: Still don't have the reason why it's not working but your answer is mainly what I needed, Big thanks +1

Comment: Most Welcome and thanks for upvote :), I will look into your code and will try to catch the issue :)